# SharePoint CAML search on Modified By

Tags: sharepoint, moss, caml

What do I use in the value to return results using the following CAML query in MOSS2007?  The query is currently not returning any results.  I have tried using the Account Name and the name displayed in the list but to now avail.

```
<Eq><FieldRef Name='Modified_x0020_By' /><Value Type='User'>domain\someusername</Value></Eq>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I managed to get this working by searching on "Author" rather than "Modified_x0020_By".

Comment: `Author` is the internal name for "Created by" ... if you want to query "Modified by", that's `Editor`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I see the internal name for the "Modified By" column is actually "Editor".

This worked for me:

```
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Editor'/><Value Type='Text'>LastName, FirstName</Value></Eq></Where>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from a query I used on the tasks list (but should be about the same):

```
Query = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
 "<Where><Eq><FieldRef ID='{0}' /><Value Type='User'>{1}</Value></Eq></Where>",
 SPBuiltInFieldId.AssignedTo, 
 SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name)
```

I used the id of the field instead of internal name though...might help you.